# Performance issue with java jdbc prepared statment and blobs

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to insert certain data one by one in an oracle database with java using jdbc thin driver.
They contain an image which i get from an ibm db2 as a hex String (also in the program).

My Problem is that i'm forced to use prepared statement since the hex string is longer than 4000 character and going that way consumes a lot of time and i'm wondering if there is a faster way to get that hex string as blob in my oracle db.

Overall it does work but it's pretty slow. For ~3400 entrys it took 24min but there are more tables with ~200.000 entrys.

here is my code for setting the values in my prep stmt (i'm not really experienced in coding/programming yet so i appreciate any sort of help)

```
while (rs.next()) { // rs = ResultSet with data
       maxCount++;
       System.out.println(maxCount);
       for (int j = 1; j <= md.getColumnCount(); j++) { // md = ResultSetMetaData
            switch (md.getColumnType(j)) {
               case 1:  // CHAR
                    oracleStmt.setString(j, rs.getString(j));
                    break;
               case -2: // BINARY
                    oracleStmt.setBlob(j, rs.getBinaryStream(j));
                    break;
               case 12: // VARCHAR
                    oracleStmt.setString(j, rs.getString(j));
                    break;
               case -1: // LONGVARCHAR
                    oracleStmt.setString(j, rs.getString(j));
                    break;
               case -3: // VARBINARY
                    oracleStmt.setBlob(j, rs.getBinaryStream(j));
                    break;
               case -4: // LONGVARBINARY
                    oracleStmt.setBlob(j, rs.getBinaryStream(j));
                    break;
               case 3: // DECIMAL
                    oracleStmt.setBigDecimal(j, rs.getBigDecimal(j));
                    break;
               case 93: // TIMESTAMP
                    oracleStmt.setTimestamp(j, rs.getTimestamp(j));
               default:
                    break;
               }
           }  
           oracleStmt.executeUpdate(); 
       }
```

My question now is how can i increase the speed of an prepared statement/ inserting hex strings as blobs using java

Comment: Have you disabled auto commit? If not: try disabling it. And out of curiosity: why are you using literal values instead of the `java.sql.Types` constants?

Comment: No i haven't disabled it, what's it purpose? and im not using the java types because one of my training supervisor said i should avoid using it. I'll try disabling auto commit.
Also i was able to get a better performance with increasing the rows of my prepared statement. Now im inserting ~500 queries at once which speeds it up from ~24min to 2min.

Comment: Auto commit will commit after every statement execute, that is really inefficient if you execute a lot of statements; committing yourself in those cases is better. Also look at the batch execute mechanism of JDBC. If your supervisor said not to use constants, he is ignoring standard practices (which is: use constants instead of magic numbers; especially if those constants are defined **in the standard**)

Comment: i think he refereed especially to those java.sql types. I'll look into the batch execute mechanism, thx for the help.

Comment: wow i used the addbatch() and executebatch() and it worked like a charm, thx a lot!

Comment: Glad to have been of help. However I would bring the use of those constants up with your supervisor. It is not as if it is an external dependency (and most of those constants have existed since Java 1.1 (or 1.2)). It is not as if those definitions won't exist at a later time..